# Invalid reference format error while trying to pull image from docker

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

The docker pull for the latest image from repository is failing with the error "Invalid reference format".
sample-project is the artifactId and the version is 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

The command is

docker pull https://docker-production.sample/sample-project:latest

Is there any syntax error in the above command?

I tried to pull the docker image from the repository with the latest commit tag, but the pull failed with Invalid reference format error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-from-a-different-registry).

> By default, docker pull pulls images from Docker Hub. It is also
> possible to manually specify the path of a registry to pull from. For
> example, if you have set up a local registry, you can specify its path
> to pull from it. A registry path is similar to a URL, but does not
> contain a protocol specifier (https://).

Doker pull command has to be in the following format.

```
docker pull REGISTRY_NAME/IMAGE_NAME:TAG

e.g: docker pull myregistry.local:5000/testing:1.2
```

In your case something like the below.

```
docker pull docker-production.sample/sample-project:latest
```

Comment: So we should not mention the https:// at the start of the url path?

Comment: @Vishal No just the URL without the protocol.